# How to get slected value of telerik rad dropdownlist inside radgrid using javascript?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have radgrid containing reddropdown inside it with autopostback=false.
when user selects value from dropdown inside grid how that value can be get through javascript.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn  UniqueName="Reminder"   HeaderStyle-Width="350px" DataField="Reminder">
                    <ItemTemplate >
                        <telerik:RadDropDownList runat="server" ID="ReminderDropDown" Width="350px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>



 <ClientSettings>
            <ClientEvents OnCommand="OnSelectedIndexChanged" />
        </ClientSettings>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
        var hiddenvalue = document.getElementById("Remindervalue");
        var s = hiddenvalue.value;
        alert("You selected item with index : " + document.getElementById(s).value);
    }
</script>
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a few changes to your code in order to make it work.

Firstly, you should register the client-side `OnClientItemSelected` event instead of the server-side `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event which only happens upon postback.

```
<telerik:RadDropDownList runat="server" ID="ReminderDropDown" Width="350px" OnClientItemSelected="OnClientItemSelected" />
```

Secondly, in your JS function, to get the client object reference of your selected item from the RadDropDownList control, you should call `eventArgs.get_item()` which will return the selected item.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnClientItemSelected(sender, eventArgs) {
        var item = eventArgs.get_item();
        alert("You selected " + item.get_text() + " with value " + item.get_value());
    }
</script>
```

Please refer to [this help article](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/dropdownlist/client-side-programming/events/onclientitemselected#onclientitemselected) for more details. Hope it helps.